# Service is not binded from activity, null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-service

Here is my code.

```
    public class ScheduleClient {

    // The hook into our service
    private ScheduleService mBoundService;
    // The context to start the service in
    private Context mContext;
    // A flag if we are connected to the service or not
    private boolean mIsBound;

    public ScheduleClient(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    public void doBindService() {
        // Establish a connection with our service
        mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext, ScheduleService.class),
                mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }


    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with our service has been
            // established,
            // giving us the service object we can use to interact with our
            // service.
            mBoundService = ((ScheduleService.ServiceBinder) service)
                    .getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mBoundService = null;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Tell our service to set an alarm for the given date
     * 
     * @param c
     *            a date to set the notification for
     */
    public void setAlarmForNotification(Calendar c) {
        if (mBoundService != null)
            mBoundService.setAlarm(c);
        else
            Log.e("@ScheduleClient", "mBoundService is null");
    }

    public void cancelAlarmForNotification() {
        mBoundService.cancelAlarm();
    }

    /**
     * When you have finished with the service call this method to stop it
     * releasing your connection and resources
     */
    public void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            mContext.unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
<service android:name="com.mobtecnica.inreez.reminder.ScheduleService" >
    </service>
```

Here `mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext, ScheduleService.class),
                    mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);` always returns false.
So `mBoundService` is became null. which means the service is not getting binded. How can I solve this issue. I am trying to setting up a reminder in my application. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the method that bounds the service and, thus, initializes `mBoundService` is `doBindService()`. This is never called. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder), there is a quite good example which does all that you need.

Comment: Yes I ve called the same
`scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(DashBoard.this);
  scheduleClient.doBindService();`